# iCloud complains that I'm running out of storage when I'm not

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, storage

I'm using the iCloud's free 5GB to backup some of my data from my iPhone. Recently, iCloud has been prompting that it's not able to perform backups because my iCloud is full.

I checked my iCloud account, and it seems like the backups took about 3GB. However, it is complaining that I'm left with only 171.92mb of storage.

[image]

I don't know how iCloud does its math because adding up all of those items in the screenshot above doesn't accumulate to 5GB.

How else can I know what was stored on my iCloud account that is occupying that other 2GB of storage? What could have happened to my iCloud account?

I'm using Windows 7 with iCloud for Windows to see the screenshot above.

Comment: It could be hidden files. I had a same problem with my USB and it turned out that there was a hidden folder that had the exact same data as I deleted. To access the iCloud files on machine, go to (CMD + G) `~/Library/Mobile Documents/` Also, show all hidden files by executing this into terminal: `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool YES` To reverse this, change YES to NO. Browse through the hidden files and see if there is duplicate. Then I would reccomend backing the data up, erasing iCloud, and putting the data back.

Comment: @TheBro21 Thanks, I will give this a try and report it here again. :) I'm on Windows7 so I'm not sure this will work. I will have to try to figure out those paths on a Windows machine too.

Comment: @TheBro21 I tried looking into my `AppData/Roaming/Apple Computer/` but I still can't find that `Mobile Documents/` folder. Any idea where this folder resides on a Windows7 system?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a windows user at all. There seems to be a windows version of icloud though [here](https://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html). It might then generate a folder with iCloud data.

Comment: @TheBro21 Well I actually had that installed already. In fact, that screen shot I took came from that windows version of iCloud. Nevertheless, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I think apple support could help you best now. They own the servers so I think they can check. They can also tell you where the directory is :)